# Barcode scanning is not working with vision API

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, android-vision, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to run the barcode-reader example ( https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader ) as it is on my Nokia 2.1 running Android 8.1.0 and Google Play Services 15.0.90. The camera starts but no barcode is detected and in the logcat I get (continuously while the camera is working) the following error:

`2019-02-09 18:17:04.990 3364-3497/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader E/BarcodeNativeHandle: Error Loading module com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source:8) at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzl.zzp(Unknown Source:39) at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzl.isOperational(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector.isOperational(Unknown Source:2) at com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector.receiveFrame(Unknown Source:16) at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSource$FrameProcessingRunnable.run(CameraSource.java:1205) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)`

What can I do to be able to run it?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any update for this issue? have you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue on Nokia 1 Android 8.1.0 Android Go edition.
Seems to be issue with vision API or Google play service issue as mentioned here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80454351

Alternately you can use zing library for barcode/qr code scanning, you can try following example, it worked for me. 
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/learn-by-doing/android-qr-code-scanner-app-tutorial-using-zxing-library/